# How to migrate local user from system to system

Tags: migration, user-accounts

I have to migrate SP 2007, which have user locals and domain users as users, to SP 2013. After migration, I am getting stuck with migrating user locals to new system. I do not know there is any way to take all users from old system to new system. I did manually add the similar username on the new system and try to login the system, access denied throws then.

Also, I go to database,edit tp_login column ( **OldDomain\account1** -> **newDomain\account1**) and create a new account with **account1** login name, result is so.

Please advice.

Comment: What approach are you using to migrate from 2007 to 2013? Are you using a third party tool or database attach upgrade process, first migrating to 2010 and then 2013?

Comment: I migrate site from 2007 to 2010 and 2013 then.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? While migrating from 2007 to 2010 or 2010 to 2013? What is the authentication type in your new web application?

Comment: on 2013 environment. Actually, old users are stored in on local computer that host SP 2007. Now I want to reuse those accounts on a new system, so i want to know a way to migrate those user.

Comment: From your question it seems that you are migrating your SharePoint to a new domain?

Answer (score 0):

From your question and comments we conclude that you are stuck from migrating SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 using Database Attach Upgrade Process. And you migrating your SharePoint to a new domain, since you mentioned this 
"(**OldDomain**\account1 -> **newDomain**\account1)".

Now I would like you to check and go through these articles and perform the steps.

[Migration from SP 2010 to 2013 user permissions not working](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/04a5dcc0-83f8-4b44-b84c-134922902010/migration-from-sp-2010-to-2013-user-permissions-not-working?forum=sharepointadmin)

[SharePoint 2010/2013: How to Move SharePoint to a New Domain](http://www.falconitservices.com/support/KB/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=194)

And always have a checklist and plan before you migrate your SharePoint to new domain. Here you go [SharePoint : Migrating SharePoint Server from one domain to another](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sushrao/archive/2011/12/02/sharepoint-migrating-sharepoint-server-from-one-domain-to-another.aspx)

If you are looking to migrate local windows users then as per my knowledge there isn't available a supported method to migrate local windows users without involving Active Directory (AD). The only way to handle this is to connect your comp1 server to Domain Controller (DC), which will promote all the local accounts to domain accounts. After this change you could join the new server to your domain as a DC and decommission the old server. That would do exactly what you want, but you'll have to use AD.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry for not explaining question clear. This system contains both domain account and window account, and Domain accounts still work after migration, but not for window account. I want to merge windows account to a new computer so that SP can authenticate those users. For example, 2007 server name is Comp1, and its window account will be Comp1\account1. After migration, it is moved to Comp2, and its window account will be like Comp2\account2. Now I like to migrate Comp1\account1 into new System. That means Comp1\account1 will be replaced with Comp2\account1. Thanks anyway, Zakir.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating more on the question. Please see my amended answer.

Comment: I then decided to migrate the users by using PowerShell to create new users that have the same name and belong to the same local group. After that, I delete all users migrated from SharePoint 2007. Finally, add them to corresponding SharePoint Group.

Comment: I first thought like you, but it is totally possible. I have to re-migrate since error will occur if I click to value of **edited** field. I have used move-SPUser command after  pefroming creating user by powershell. I then also have to change display name for those accounts. I have test login with new migrated users, and I can view their user information. I works for me. Thanks for support anyway, Zakir.