# SharePoint local users moved to another server

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, migration, user-accounts

We are moving a SharePoint Server to another server, is there a simple way to handle local users?
We need them to have the same login, but if you migrate the databases the userinfo remains from the old server.

Example: computername1\user1
after migration we would want to change in the all user list just change the computername1 to computername2.
These are not and cannot be domain users.

I have found similar thread, but it's been a while since then so I thought if something has changed or someone found solution. [How to migrate local user from system to system](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138426/how-to-migrate-local-user-from-system-to-system)

If we change this directly on the database it does not seem to work. My colleague said that due to the size of the data and databases the SP migrate user would take too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you mount the content database on the target server, you can use [Move-SPUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/move-spuser?view=sharepoint-ps) to migrate users from one domain to another domain.

A similar thread for your reference:
[Migrating SharePoint 2013 Servers to new Domain (Same Version and Build): Best Practice](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/239596/migrating-sharepoint-2013-servers-to-new-domain-same-version-and-build-best-p)